# MYSQL PHP No Database Selected - Can't Find Error

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?
require_once('etcore.php');
mysql_connect($dburl,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("rshost") or die(mysql_error());
$username=strtoupper(clean($_POST['username']));
$password=md5($_POST['password']);
$andover = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE usernameupper='$username' AND password='$password'") or die(mysql_error().__LINE__);
$numberofthings = mysql_num_rows($andover) or die(mysql_error().__LINE__);
if ($numberofthings = 1) {
    $getit=mysql_fetch_array($andover) or die(mysql_error().__LINE__);
    $_SESSION['id'] = $getit['id'];
    header('Location: index.php');
}
else {
?>
<h1>Login:</h1>
<img src='http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Warning.png' width="25" height="25" />
<strong style="color:#F03;">Incorrect Username and/or Password </strong><br>
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
Username: <input name="username" type="text" /><br />
Password: <input name="password" type="password" /><br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In!" /><br />
</form>
<? } ?>
```

This is the code I am using. Whenever I run the code, I get the error "No database selected" on line 7. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! BTW: Db user, pass and URL are all in the 'etcore.php' file, so it is not a problem there. I have also tried replacing those variables with strings and get the same error.

Comment: Which one is line 7? the `$andover = mysql_query(...)` one?

Comment: Try saving the connection handle and passing it explicitly. Any change you are creating a new connection to the database in the clean function? Anyway, worth trying: $res = mysql_connect(); mysql_select_db("rshost", $res); mysql_query(..., $res);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
mysql_select_db("rshost", mysql_connect($dburl,$dbuser,$dbpass))
```

or even better:

```
$handle = mysql_connect($dburl,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db("rshost", $handle);
```

And maybe for a better knowledge and understanding: 
[manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)

in the section **parameters**
so it would be clear why it may OR may not work without using the `$handle` argument

Answer (score 0):

Give the database privileges. May be you don't have the user permission to access database,
check this

```
mysql> grant all privileges on Databasename.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by password
```

Comment: This actually solved my problem! Apparently old mysql functions does not tell the truth on error - jet another reason why we shouldn't use them!